# How does the `auto` keyword work in lambda functions?

Tags: c++, c++14, auto

I am new to templates and lambdas function and I am trying to understand what's happening in this piece of code:

```cpp
function<void (const int &)> foo = [&](auto x) {
    x = 42;
}
```

Here, I assume the compiler is able to tell from the `auto` keyword that `x` has type `const int &`. Therefore, the compiler should not allow the assignment `x = 42`.

However, this code compiles without error, which confuses me. Why does the compiler allow this? What did the compiler actually deduced for the `auto` keyword?

Comment: The left hand side of the assignment is not involved in template deduction.

Comment: Don't spam C++ versions in the tags unless you ask about a difference between the versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auto` is never deduced to a reference. It always deduces to a decayed type.

When passed a `const int &` (or any reference to some type `T`), then it will be deduced to `int` (or the decayed type `T`). (Or to be more precise, when passed an expression of type `T` with any value category, it will always deduce to the decayed type `T`. Types of expressions never include references, which are instead translated into value categories.)

You can still assign the lambda, because it is possible to initialize an `int` from a `const int&` (or more precisely from an lvalue expression of type `const int`). This is what will happen when you call `foo`.

So you are assigning here to a local parameter object inside the function. The assignment is not visible outside the lambda.

If you want to deduce a reference, use `auto&&`. This however will then *always* deduce a reference. It also won't decay the type, so the `const` will be retained.

Comment: So, in my code example, am I correct to understand that the `const` and `&` inside `function<...>` has no effect at all? i.e. I might as well just write `function<void (int)> foo = [&](auto x) { x = 42; }`, which is exactly the same for the compiler?

Comment: @iluvmath: They have no effect on the lambda. `auto` in a function signature is *exactly* like a template parameter. `template<typename T> void func(T t);` works the same way.

Comment: @iluvmath You should decide the type in the `function` template argument based on how `foo` is going to be called, not based on what function you store inside it. If you intent `foo` to be used as if it takes by-value, then it should be `int`. If it it supposed to behave like it takes a `const int` reference, then `const int&`. However, for simple types like `int` there is usually no difference between the two and it is common to pass by-value. Whether or not the parameter in the lambda is `const` is independent of this.

Comment: @iluvmath Imagine that `foo` is just a normal function with the type you specified for it and which happens to do nothing but call another function (the one stored in the `std::function` object, here the lambda), forwarding the arguments it was given.

Comment: I see. Got it. My confusion was that I didn't understand `std::function` is just a general-purpose polymorphic function wrapper, completely independent of the lambda. It's clear to me now. Thank you.